# R: Loop Only Saves the Final Iteration?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, aggregate, data-manipulation

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to create a file called "combine" that looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
#generate data
set.seed(123)
var = rnorm(731, 100,25)
date= seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")
data = data.frame(var,date)


#analysis for "99"

data$var_99 = 99
data$new_var_99 = ifelse(data$var >99,1,0)

#percent of observations greater than 99 (each month)
aggregate_99 = data %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
    summarise( mean = mean(new_var_99))


#analysis for "98"

data$var_98 = 98
data$new_var_98 = ifelse(data$var >98,1,0)

#percent of observations greater than 98 (each month)
aggregate_98 = data %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
    summarise( mean = mean(new_var_98))

#combine files together 

aggregate_98$var = 98
aggregate_98$var = as.factor(aggregate_98$var)

aggregate_99$var = 99
aggregate_99$var = as.factor(aggregate_99$var)

combine = rbind(aggregate_98, aggregate_99)
```

I now want to try to create this "combine" file using a loop:

```
for (i in 98:100) {

data$var_i = i
data$new_var_i = ifelse(data$var >i,1,0)

#percent of observations greater than i (each month)
aggregate_i = data %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
    summarise( mean = mean(new_var_i))

#combine files together 

aggregate_i$var = i
aggregate_i$var = as.factor(aggregate_i$var)

combine = rbind(aggregate_i)

}
```

However, it seems to me that this loop only stores the results of the final iteration (i = 100) :

```
 combine = data.frame(combine)
combine
     month      mean var
1  2014-01 0.5161290 100
2  2014-02 0.5000000 100
3  2014-03 0.4516129 100
4  2014-04 0.6000000 100
5  2014-05 0.4193548 100
6  2014-06 0.5000000 100
7  2014-07 0.4516129 100
8  2014-08 0.6129032 100
9  2014-09 0.5000000 100
10 2014-10 0.4838710 100
11 2014-11 0.3333333 100
12 2014-12 0.6451613 100
13 2015-01 0.4838710 100
14 2015-02 0.3214286 100
15 2015-03 0.5483871 100
16 2015-04 0.4333333 100
17 2015-05 0.3870968 100
18 2015-06 0.5666667 100
19 2015-07 0.5806452 100
20 2015-08 0.3225806 100
21 2015-09 0.5333333 100
22 2015-10 0.3548387 100
23 2015-11 0.5333333 100
24 2015-12 0.7096774 100
25 2016-01 1.0000000 100
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this loop so that all iterations are recorded?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the final line `combine = rbind(aggregate_i)` you are overwriting `combine` in each iteration. I think you were trying to do `combine = rbind(combine, aggregate_i)`. However, growing dataframes in a for loop can be inefficient. Store the data in a list and then combine them into one.

```
library(dplyr)

vals <- 98:100
combine <- vector('list', length(vals))
count <- 0
for (i in vals) {
  
  data$var_i = i
  data$new_var_i = ifelse(data$var >i,1,0)
  
  #percent of observations greater than i (each month)
  aggregate_i = data %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
    group_by(month = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
    summarise( mean = mean(new_var_i))
  
  #combine files together 
  
  aggregate_i$var = i
  aggregate_i$var = as.factor(aggregate_i$var)
  
  count <- count + 1
  combine[[count]] <- aggregate_i
  
}

result <- bind_rows(combine)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! this works, but I am unable to take the "combine" file and pass it through a plotly command (: semi colons are used to indicate a new line of code): library(plotly); gg <-ggplot(combine, aes(frame = var)) + geom_line(aes(x=month, y=mean, group=1))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90)) + ggtitle("title") ; ggplotly(gg)

Comment: Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a list

Comment: I tried to manually convert "combine" into a data frame : combine <- as.data.frame(combine) .... and then pass it through the "plotly" command .... but this still does not work. Do you have any ideas why this might be happening? thanks for all your help!

Comment: You need to use `result` in `ggplot` code which is `result <- bind_rows(combine)`.

Comment: Thank you for everything. Can you please take a look at this question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66141967/r-switching-between-graphs thank you