# R: Switching Between Graphs

Tags: r, onclick, plotly, data-visualization, interactive

I am using the R programming language. I am trying to follow the tutorial here on "switching between graphs" : https://plotly.com/r/dropdowns/ (first example).

First, I generated some data in R:

```
library(plotly)
library(MASS)

x <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25) )
y <- rnorm(1000,10,10)
z <- rnorm(1000,5,5)
    
    df <- data.frame(x,y, z)
df$x = as.factor(df$x)
    colnames(df) <- c("x", "y", "z")
```

I tried to modify the code from this tutorial to make the final result:

```
fig <- plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z alpha = 0.3)
fig <- fig %>% add_markers(marker = list(line = list(color = "black", width = 1)))
fig <- fig %>% layout(
    title = "Drop down menus - Plot type",
    xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
    yaxis = list(title = "y"),
    updatemenus = list(
        list(
            y = 0.8,
            buttons = list(
                
                list(method = "restyle",
                     args = list("type", "scatter"),
                     label = "Scatter A"),
                
                list(method = "restyle",
                     args = list("type", "scatter"),
                     label = "Scatter B"),
                
                list(method = "restyle",
                     args = list("type", "scatter"),
                     label = "Scatter C"),
                
                list(method = "restyle",
                     args = list("type", "scatter"),
                     label = "Scatter D")
                
                
            ))
```

But this does not seem to be working.

Instead, I had a different idea: Perhaps I could create a series of graphs that I want to be able to "switch" between:

```
df_1 <- df[which(df$x == "A"),]
df_2 <- df[which(df$x == "B"),]
df_3 <- df[which(df$x == "C"),]
df_4 <- df[which(df$x == "D"),]


graph_1 <- plot_ly( data = df_1, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", x = ~ y, y = ~z) %>% layout(title = "graph 1")

graph_2 <- plot_ly( data = df_2, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", x = ~ y, y = ~z) %>% layout(title = "graph 2")

graph_3 <- plot_ly( data = df_3, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", x = ~ y, y = ~z) %>% layout(title = "graph 3")

graph_4 <- plot_ly( data = df_4, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", x = ~ y, y = ~z) %>% layout(title = "graph 4")

graph_5 <- plot_ly(df, y = ~y, color = ~x, type = "box") %>% layout(title = "boxplot")
```

Now, is it possible to modify the plotly code to "tie" all these graphs (graph_1, graph_2, graph_3, graph_4, graph_5) together, so that the user can click the tab on the left and switch between these graphs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you should look at the tutorial is the last one (with the sine waves). It hides and shows different traces of the plot depending on the value of the selection in the dropdown menu.

You just need to change the format of your dataframe to wide.

```
df.wide <- df %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from=z)

df.wide
## A tibble: 1,000 x 5
#       y     D     B       A     C
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  6.48  6.21 NA    NA      NA   
# 2 23.6  NA    15.3  NA      NA   
# 3 -9.99 -2.16 NA    NA      NA   
# 4 19.6  NA    NA     0.0683 NA   
# 5 18.8  -1.40 NA    NA      NA   
# 6 -2.71  9.80 NA    NA      NA   
# 7  2.32 NA    NA    NA       3.77
# 8 11.9  NA     4.35 NA      NA   
# 9 21.4  NA    NA    NA      13.9 
#10  2.34 NA     2.10 NA      NA   
## … with 990 more rows
```

Then add a separate scatter trace for each column. In the arguments of the dropdown menu you can set which traces are going to be visible when each option is selected. For example `args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))` means that only the first trace added (in this case column `A`) is going to be visible.

```
fig <- plot_ly(df.wide, x = ~y)
fig <- fig %>% 
  add_trace(y = ~A, name = "A", type='scatter', mode='markers') %>% 
  add_trace(y = ~B, name = "B", type='scatter', mode='markers', visible = F) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~C, name = "C", type='scatter', mode='markers', visible = F) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~D, name = "D", type='scatter', mode='markers', visible = F) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
         yaxis = list(title = "y"),
         updatemenus = list(
           list(
             y = 0.7,
             buttons = list(
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "A"),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "B"),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
                    label = "C"),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
                    label = "D")))))
```

[image]
[image]

#### EDIT: Adding also a box plot

Adding an option for a different type of plot (like a box plot) is a little bit harder. The issue now is that x axis in the box plot and scatter plot are different. So you can't use the same axis. Fortunately, plotly lets you map different traces to different axis. Then you can set the position of this new axis within the complete plot using the `domain` attribute.

My solution is a little bit hacky because I used the `domain` attribute to "hide" the "plot" I did not want to use by making it very small (I also made the corresponding data invisible by setting `visible = FALSE`). This is because hiding the axis only hides the lines. You are still left with the background of the plot.

Note that now I use the method `update` (instead of `restyle`) because it allows you to change also the layout of the plot (https://plotly.com/r/custom-buttons/).

But it seemed to work very well!

```
# I had to reorder the dataframe because the boxplot was not following the order of the factors. Apparently it follows the orders that the letter appear.
df <- df %>% dplyr::arrange(x)

df.wide <- df %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from=z)

# this is a list with axis config for scatter plot (define here to avoid repetition)
axis.config.scatter <- list(xaxis = list(title = "x", domain = c(0.1, 1), visible=T),
                            yaxis = list(title = "y", domain = c(0, 1), visible=T),
                            xaxis2 = list(title = "group", domain = c(0.99, 1), visible=F),
                            yaxis2 = list(title = "y", domain = c(0,99, 1), visible=F))

# this is a list with axis config for box plot (define here to avoid repetition)
axis.config.box <- list(xaxis = list(title = "x", domain = c(0.99, 1), visible=F),
                        yaxis = list(title = "y", domain = c(0.99, 1), visible=F),
                        xaxis2 = list(title = "group", domain = c(0.1, 1), visible=T, anchor='free'),
                        yaxis2 = list(title = "y", domain = c(0, 1), visible=T, anchor='free'))


fig <- plot_ly(df.wide)
fig <- fig %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~y, y = ~A, name = "A", type='scatter', mode='markers') %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~y, y = ~B, name = "B", type='scatter', mode='markers', visible = F) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~y, y = ~C, name = "C", type='scatter', mode='markers', visible = F) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~y, y = ~D, name = "D", type='scatter', mode='markers', visible = F) %>% 
  add_trace(data=df, x=~x, y=~z, name='box', type='box', visible=F, xaxis='x2', yaxis='y2') %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "x", domain = c(0.1, 1)),
         yaxis = list(title = "y"),
         xaxis2 = list(title = "group", domain = c(0.99, 1), visible=F),
         yaxis2 = list(title = "y", domain = c(0.99, 1), visible=F),
         updatemenus = list(
           list(
             y = 0.7,
             buttons = list(
               list(method = "update",
                    args = list(list(visible = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                                axis.config.scatter),
                    label = "A"),
               list(method = "update",
                    args = list(list(visible = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                                axis.config.scatter),
                    label = "B"),
               list(method = "update",
                    args = list(list(visible = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                                axis.config.scatter),
                    label = "C"),
               list(method = "update",
                    args = list(list(visible = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
                                axis.config.scatter),
                    label = "D"),
               list(method = "update",
                    args = list(list(visible = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
                                axis.config.box),
                    label = "box")
               ))))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your help! i spent the whole day yesterday trying to get this to work. the only thing i wanted to ask : suppose if I wanted to add a "box plot" to the "fig" . something like this: add_trace(y = ~y, name = "E", type='box', mode='markers', visible = F) %>%  .... since the pivot_wider command has been used to reformat the data, is this still possible?

Comment: You mean you would like a box plot comparing A, B, C and D? Note that you can use different datasets in each trace. So you could create this boxplot by using setting `data=df` (the original dataframe) in the new trace.

Comment: I gave it a try and it is not working because a boxplot has a discrete x axis and a scatter plot a continuous y axis. And it is not allowing the two types of x axis to be "mixed". Not sure if you can do it... If I can get it to work, I will update my answer.

Comment: thank you for everything, i am also trying this on my end. is the pivot_wider statement really necessary? in the past, I have used approaches like htmtools::taglist() or as you have shown me in a previous example plotly::subplot() to "glue" different plots together. i am trying to see if there is a way to do this without using the pivot_wider().

Comment: @Noob: I updated my answer with a way of including a box plot too. Probably there are other ways of doing it without `pivot_wider` (there are usually several ways of getting similar results). I learned a lot trying to answer this one! Hope this helps you!

Comment: thank you so much! i will try this right now (I posted my progress over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66161597/gluing-graphs-together-trouble-with-traces-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic) ... I can not thank you enough for your help!

Comment: If you have time, can you please take a look at this question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201634/r-titles-on-graphs-not-updating thank you